# Wrong answer from DIV assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I have a part of my code

```
mov di,3                                                           
mov cx,16
  looop:
  xor dx,dx
  shl bx,1
  adc dx,dx
  cmp cx,16
  je cx16 (it's will dec cx and jump loop)

  push dx
  dec cx
  cmp cx,0
  je  cx0
  mov ax,cx
  div di

cmp dx,0
jne looop
```

when cx = 3
i will get ax =3
But `div di`
ax will become H=55 L= 56
and dx = 1
Please could you tell me what did i do wrong here?

Comment: When I run your program, after `div di` I am getting `al=5 , ah=0 , dx=0`. I am using EMU8086. Before 'div di', ax = 15 (because cx was 16 but `dec x`), `di = 3 ` and `dx = 0`, so, 15 / 3 = 5.

Comment: so the answer depends on machine?

Comment: i forgot je cx16 will dec cx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`div di` divides the 32 bit quantity `dx:ax` by `di`. We don't know what value your `bx` has, but presumably it produces `dx=1` (due to the `adc dx, dx`). So the division is going to be `0x10003 / 3 = 0x5556` remainder `1`, and that's exactly what you see.

PS: learn to use a debugger, and read the instruction set reference as appropriate.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, you probably need to zero `dx` before the `div`.

Comment: Could u recommend me about book of assembly